# Can't get navigation menu links to display inline and not one after the other

Tags: html, css

With this snipit of html I'm trying to get my menu to display at the top of the page with each link following to the right of the prev one. However at the moment they display one after the other. I've tried to style it with the shown CSS.

Can someone tell me whats wrong with this?

```
<nav class="grid_4 topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Cheeses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>



.topmenu {
    display:inline; 
    margin: 2% 0;
        padding: 1% 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you added the class into nav it wont work, because it the `display: inline;` not excute in li tags, he excute the display in nav tag.

so all I had to do is add `.topmenu li` element instead `.topmenu`, like that:

```
.topmenu li {
    display:inline; 
    margin: 2% 0;
    padding: 1% 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2u4s/)

Comment: Using this, can I still use background-image: url('css/bg.jpg');  to style the background of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to @Yotam's suggestion is to use a left `float` with a list decoration of `none`.

The code looks like this:

```
.topmenu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 1% 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMGWt/)